# Use Powershell to Download Webfiles Based on UTF8 Text File List

Tags: powershell, file-download, recursive, textfiles

**Aiming to**

- download website files via powershell;
- get the name from each line of a text file;
- with UTF8 support (supporting international text names);
- & save the files to a directory with the same name.

*This script will be then applied to 20+ folders to save tedious work.*

**Test One:**

```
Get-Content "C:\test\filename.txt" | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "http://Website_Address/$_.mp3" }
```

[image: Powershell Screen Print]

**Test Two**

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$client.DownloadFile("https://web.com/name.mp3","C:\test\name.mp3")
```

*Downloads Single File Correctly*

**Test Three**

```
Get-Content "C:\test\filename.txt" | ForEach-Object {
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$client.DownloadFile("https://web.com/'$_'.mp3","C:\test\'$_'.mp3")
 }
Clear-Variable -Name "client"
```

[image: Powershell Error]
*(Giving Errors 2 and does not save as expected, spent several hours on it)*

**Filename.txt**

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
88888
99999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Download Website Files Via Powershell using Text File for FileNames with UTF8 support.**

- The quotation marks '$*' around the $* was what was causing the script to fail in test three.
- The 2 errors turned out to be 2 empty lines in the text file.
- Clear Variable, I think is unnecessary, but it was in there due different attempts of scripting.

**Final Solution**

download.ps1

```
Get-Content "C:\test\filename.txt" | ForEach-Object {
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$client.DownloadFile("https://webname.com/$_.mp3","C:\test\$_.mp3")
 }
Clear-Variable -Name "client"
```

[image: works without error]

- Powershell works without any errors

[image: Files Downloaded]

- Files download and offsite test shows UTF8 Names works